# table not found using h2 database ? login is table name which cannot found in logcat?

Tags: android, xml, jdbc, h2

Please check this code...

```
String uid=user.getText().toString();
String pwd=passwd.getText().toString();
Connection conn=DbConnection.getConnection();
PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO LOGIN (USERNAME,PASSWORD) VALUES('rkkk','bang')");

pstmt.setString(1,uid);
pstmt.setString(2,pwd);
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: What is your database URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to ddms -> file explorer -> sdcard -> push .db file. and disconnect ur h2 database.after push and run
hope so it will work.